# Comparación de fechas para seleccionar las que se encuentran en un rango de x días

Tags: java, date

```
System.out.print("Ingrese el Rango de dias que desee: ");

int dias = input.nextInt();

LocalDate ahora = LocalDate.now();
```

Tengo una lista de fechas de cumpleaños y quiero compararlas con una fecha futura, que es el resultado de la fecha de hoy más `x` días para seleccionar a las que se encuentran en ese rango. No tengo idea de cómo hacerlo, sí puedo hacer la sumatoria de los días pero no sé como compararlas.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando compares fechas usa `isBefore` o `isAfter`. En tu caso:

```
if(ahora.isBefore(fecha) && ahora.plusDays(dias).isAfter(fecha)) {
    System.out.print("Esta en el rango ");
}
```